# How to get margin left size using javascript when I use margin auto property in css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `div` with `margin:auto;` and I need get only `margin-left` size value using javascript `:)`

```
//css
.test{
        margin: auto;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        outline: 1px solid red;
    }


 // html
        <div class="test">Test</div>
```

[Live example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gpojgo)

Comment: try `alert(document.getElementById("test").offsetLeft);`

Comment: replace to `<div class="test" id="test"></div>`

Comment: with jquery: `$(".test").offset().left;`

Comment: answer me and I submit your answer :) thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome, I answer. Good luck

Comment: good question thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

1) With jQuery

```
var left = $(".test").offset().left;
```

2) Or, second version is that: 
Replace your div to `<div class="test" id="test"></div>`, and use this js.

```
var left = document.getElementById("test").offsetLeft;
```

Comment: this does not work when the element has auto margins. calculating the difference of the BoundingClientRect between container and element is required for that case.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method if you don't need IE8 support.

```
 var test = document.querySelector('.test');
 var left_margin = window.getComputedStyle(test).getPropertyValue("margin-left"); // returns margin e.g. '655px'
 left_margin = left_margin.match(/\d+/); //returns bare number e.g. '655'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for that, plain JavaScript is enough:

```
var left, element = document.querySelector('.test');
if(element) {
  left = element.getBoundingClientRect().left;  
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return margins, it returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect